# Remote Debugging Laravel HomeStead not working

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I have followed step by step instructions at https://medium.com/@skboadu/debugging-laravel-homestead-applications-with-phpstorm-444ccc1ddef2 to set up remote xdebug debugging on Laravel Homestead. Only difference is I have PHP 7.1 but that should not matter.

After setting the breakpoints, enabling "Listening for Debug Connections", and setting breakpoints on the home page I am unable to see anything happen?

My config for both FPM and CLI:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

I also have "PHPSTORM" as the IDE in Xdebug helper and nothing seems to happen. I tried setting up a log on xdebug config but nothing gets recorded.

What am I doing wrong? I followed the instructions step by step.

Comment: 1) Collect xdebug logs https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) If xdebug logs does not get collected for some reason -- maybe it does not see the incoming "debug me" marker. Either place `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint; will also trigger debug session) or `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini (so it will try to debug every single request`. Hopefully that will generate the log. Then you can proceed further from there.

Comment: Could also be http://stackoverflow.com/q/30559679/783119

Answer (score 0):

Check that port 9000 is open on your Host and that your IDE is listening for connections on that port.

You also lack `remote_autostart` in case you want it to just stop at breakpoints on it's own without you having to start the debugger beforehand.

In my usage i've had to set up a server in PHPStorm and Remote Debugger as well and set up the path mappings between my host and vagrant machines.